# if one field is not empty then all required not empty

Tags: php

Is there an efficient way of processing part of a form that has three input fields. If all are empty then don't do anything, but if one is filled, all must be filled.

At the moment I have this

```
if (isset($_POST['desc1']) && !empty($_POST['desc1'])){
$email_message .= $_POST['desc1']. " - " . $_POST['code1']. " - Amount: " .$_POST['quant1']."<br>";
$toadd .= $_POST['desc1']. " - " . $_POST['code1']. " - Amount: " .$_POST['quant1']."<br><br>"; 
}
```

Problem is they could have entered the `desc1` but not the `code1` or `quant1` and it will fire anyway. If they entered `code1` or `quant1` and not the `desc1` nothing will happen, which again is a problem, I would like to display this as an error and have them go back and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this.

```
$required = array('desc1', 'code1', 'quant1');
$errors = array();
$fields_set = 0;

foreach ($required as $rq) {
    if (isset($_POST[$rq])) {
        $fields_set++;
    } else {
        $errors[$rq] = "{$rq} is not set...";
    }
}

$valid = ($fields_set == 0 || $fields_set == count($required)) ? true : false;

if ($valid) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    print_r($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
if(!isset($_POST['desc1']) &&
   !isset($_POST['code1']) &&
   !isset($_POST['quant1'])  {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
   }
elseif(!isset($_POST['desc1']) ||
   !isset($_POST['code1']) ||
   !isset($_POST['quant1'])  {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
   }
```